# Error while trying to install npm package 'libxmljs'

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, libxml-js

I am getting the following error message when I try to install libxmljs npm package.

```
$ sudo npm install -g libxmljs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/libxmljs
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/libxmljs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.0.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/-/bindings-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/-/bindings-1.0.0.tgz

> libxmljs@0.8.1 install /usr/lib/node_modules/libxmljs
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/home/support/.node-gyp/0.10.23"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/libxmljs/.node-gyp"
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.23/node-v0.10.23.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.23/node-v0.10.23.tar.gz
make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/libxmljs/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/buf.o
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/libxml/vendor/libxml/buf.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/libxmljs/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.23
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! libxmljs@0.8.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.8.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the libxmljs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls libxmljs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "libxmljs"
npm ERR! cwd /
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.23
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.17
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have node-gyp version 0.12.1 installed in my system which is a prerequisite for libxmljs. Node version is v0.10.23.

Can anyone please guide me in resolving the issue.

Comment: `make: cc: Command not found` Try
`sudo apt-get install gcc`

Comment: This question doesn't belong here.

Comment: Could you please track where it is breaking by using command "sudo npm install -g libxmljs --verbose"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eraden said `make: cc: Command not found` was the problem. `sudo apt-get install gcc` solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've added my own answer as I needed to install another package.

Answer (score 0):

Looks your system node and npm is not upto date.

Use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)(Node Version Manager) to run multiple node.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the reference, in my case, on a Centos 7, I had to install also gcc-c++:

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++.x86_64
```

Only in this way I was able to install libxmljs.